# read columns/headers of csv files only

Tags: r, csv, filter, header, data-import

i have tried some code but i cant come up with a solution, my problem is as follows.

I have a working directory with many separated csv files and unique names.
There are 34 different types of files, depending on there number of columns, some have the columns A to C, others have A to E. What they have in common is that every file has the columns A and B.

What i want to do now, i want to sort/filter them according to their number and type of columns.

e.g.: Type 1: Column A+B, Type 2: Column A + B + C, Type 3: Column A + C + D ...

The reuslt should then look something like:

Type1       Type 2
Filename A  Filename D
Filename B  Filename E
Filename C  Filename F...

For the purpose to use different methods on eahc individual type then, so i have the similar type of datastructures under one "column"

I tried to use a function i found which could be used on data which is already "clean":

```
load_data <- function(path) { 
  files <- dir(path, pattern = '\\.csv', full.names = TRUE)
  tables <- lapply(files, read.csv("", nrows=1, header=TRUE, sep=","))
  do.call(rbind, tables)
}

identifier <- load_data("path")
```

As the data is pretty big i think thiswould be the best way.

Another solution i could htink of would be to gerenate single dataframes for each file, and put them together in a list, and then filter according to the number of indexes?

Thank you very much for your help,

BR

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to do different analysis on each "Type" of file, and therefore i would like to have the files filtered beforehand so i can apply the different methods on the different files, or other way around:
I want to see, which file belongs to which type, according to the number of columns, as i dont want to open, in my case ~4000 files, and manually count how many columns are there and then move the file to another directory or write it down manually on a list, i hope its a bit clearer now, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i figured out a way to do it, but its really slow:

```
path <- "path"
name_list <- dir(path)
df <- data.frame()
i <- 1
for(i in 1:length(name_list)){
  ident = dim(read.csv(paste(path,name_list[i], sep ="/"), nrows=2, header=TRUE, sep=","))
  df[i,1] <- cbind(name_list[i])
  df[i,2] <- cbind(ident[2])
}
```

Perhaps there could be a workaround with the `apply` function?